# Print a varaible

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Pls Why I can't print my variable ?

```
set var a
toplevel .window
frame .window.frame0
label .window.frame0.label0 -textvariable var
pack .window.frame0.label0 -side left
pack .window.frame0 -side top
```

Comment: Because you've not used a command to print the variable?

Comment: You have a typo in the last command.  If you fix that, the label becomes visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved.
I need to declare var as global. The option -textvariable use only global variable.
Finaly :

```
proc foo {} {
global var
set var a
toplevel .window
frame .window.frame0
label .window.frame0.label0 -textvariable var
pack .window.frame0.label0 -side left
pack .window.frame0 -side top
}
```

Comment: Which illustrates the importance of giving all relevant information when asking a question.